# Error no matching distribution found for MarkupSafe==1.0

Tags: python, pip

Trying to install libraries in a newly created environment after using the command

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And got an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\mynewflaskenv\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bhlep5x0\\markupsafe_32ada0e4f7c949d6829afd169418e437\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bhlep5x0\\markupsafe_32ada0e4f7c949d6829afd169418e437\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ud9uf7zf'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhlep5x0\markupsafe_32ada0e4f7c949d6829afd169418e437\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bhlep5x0\markupsafe_32ada0e4f7c949d6829afd169418e437\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature' from 'setuptools' (C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py)
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/de/32d741db316d8fdb7680822dd37001ef7a448255de9699ab4bfcbdf4172b/MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz#sha256=a6be69091dac236ea9c6bc7d012beab42010fa914c459791d627dad4910eb665 (from https://pypi.org/simple/markupsafe/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MarkupSafe==1.0 (from versions: 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 1.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MarkupSafe==1.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try making the MarkupSafe requirement from 1.0 to 1.1.1.

Like this:

```
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
```

Why is this happening?

As user [jbflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12959994/jbflow) states in the comments: "These kind of problems come up when you use a newer version of Python than the one that was used when requirements.txt was frozen."

Comment: worked well, now i have the following errors below, specific library versions uninstalled and 4 incompatible. can anything be done about the incompatible libs

Comment: These kind of problems come up when you use a newer version of Python than the one that was used when requirements.txt was frozen. Make sure you create the env using the right version of Python for the project and it should work. Or you could also go through them one by one installing the latest versions of the packages as the devs would likely have updated the packages to work with newer versions.